# architecture x86_64 after building

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

i'm using xcode 7 and when I build I face this problem

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

is there any thing missing ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using Google Maps framework in your project.

Make sure you add all the necessary frameworks needed for Google Maps framework

Follow through this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) to install Google Maps SDK